# How to hide window buttons and tittle bar in Golang Fyne

Tags: go, user-interface, fyne

How can I remove default minimize, maximize, close buttons and tittle bar?
I've read fyne.io , but didn't find any information about tittlebar there. Maybe I missed something.

I found a similar question, but I still don't understand how to implement it. I am a complete beginner (

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :)

```
drv := fyne.CurrentApp().Driver()
if drv, ok := drv.(desktop.Driver); ok {
    w := drv.CreateSplashWindow()
}
```